# Meteg on a short vowel

Tags: trop-cantillation, vowels-nekudot

Short vowels are closed with a consonant when unstressed. A cantillation  (trope) can set off a short vowel as an open vowel. Can a meteg do the same thing? 
I have seen a meteg do as such on the guttural letters and resh, but these can be open vowels even without a meteg as in the word mirachefes (Genesis 1:2). This is because there would have been a dagesh chazack (in the ches), but those letters can't have a dagesh chazak. I have also seen the meteg do this job on a kubutz and chirik, but not on a patach or segol. So maybe it can change a short vowel into its long counterpart, but not on a patach or segol which don't have long versions of the same kind.

I don't think there is a difference between the meteg and trope itself. Rather, the differece can be because the trope represents the primary stress, while the meteg is a secondary stress in the same word.

Answer (score 1):

A meteg can indeed set a short vowel in an open syllable.

Comment: Can you give an example with a patach or segol when the letter afterward is not guttural or resh?